# is it possible to convert bitlocker encrypted GPT drive to MBR?

Tags: ssd, mbr, bitlocker, gpt

I have found some guides how to do this in diskpart or by using EaseUS partition master, but they don't mention if it would work with Bitlocker.
And before you ask me why I want that - to be able to run SpinRite on that drive. I have a good experience with it even on SSD it seems to have fixed my father's pc weird performance problems and I have a feeling there might be troubles on my work laptop drive as well.

Comment: Converting to MBR to GPT without data loss won’t be possible if your drive is encrypted.  You will have to turn off BitLocker, do the conversion, then and only then enable it.  However, this is not recommended, GPT is superior to MBr

Comment: @Ramhound But will it boot after the conversion?

Comment: Most conversions between GPT and MBR involve total data loss, encrypted or not. Some third-party utilities may be able to do that, but don't count on it.

Comment: Then I guess I will rather hope that Steve Gibson will make the SpinRite 6.1 which would work with GPT but he promises it for more then a decade already :-]